# jupyter notebook default folder won't change

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I tried changing the start in field of the shortcut, and I created the the config.py file and wrote c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'D:\Jupyter' and made sure it's uncommented.

Note that when I open Jupyter Notebook from the Anaconda prompt it does open in the desired folder. I'm trying to make it work with the shortcut.

[image: A print screen]

This picture shows the properties of the shortcut and the relevant part of the config.py, as well as showing the Jupyter Notebook virtual server is attached.

I consulted the following link before posting my question
(not hyperlinked due to lack of reputation):
https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/44luwc/how_to_change_jupyter_start_folder/

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

[Changing Jupyter Notebook start up folder by modifying "start in" not working any more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505712/changing-jupyter-notebook-start-up-folder-by-modifying-start-in-not-working-an)

[Jupyter Notebook Set Default Folder to Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657137/jupyter-notebook-set-default-folder-to-root)

[jupyter notebook starting directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252884/jupyter-notebook-starting-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `u` before your path.

I've run Anaconda and Jupyter on several Windows environments, and my path has always worked, but I've never used the Unicode modifier. I don't believe it's needed. So try:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'D:\\Jupyter'
```

The double `\` is needed to escape the character

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Browse to the Jupyter Notebook file location and open the configuration file in Notepad:

```sh
C:\Users\username\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Step 2: Search for the following line in the file:

```
#c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''
```

And replace it with:

```
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'C:/the/path of/folder/where you/want to set/'
```

Step 3: Finally, go to where your shortcut to the Jupyter Notebook is located; e.g.:

```
C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)
```

And do the following:

- Go to the *Properties* of Jupyter Notebook link.
- In the *Target* field, remove `%USERPROFILE%`, as @stenlytw suggested above.
- Then, in the *Start in* field, type the same directory you set above:

```
C:\path of folder\where you\want to set\in jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

> **Just remember!** In the `notebook_config.py` file, the path is enclosed within apostrophes (`'…'`), and uses a forward slash (`/`) as the directory delimiter—but in properties, you don't use the apostrophes, and instead use a backslash (`\`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an altenative which I have not seen anyone mentioned anywhere:

**Keep the default directories all the same and simply create a bookmark in your browser.**

For example, my python code is at C:\Users[name]\Documents\Code\Python, so I have a bookmark for **"http://localhost:8888/tree/Documents/Code/Python"** in my toolbar.

As soon as Jupyter opens a tab in your browser, hit the button. It requires one extra click, yes, but saves you from some possibly annoying tinkering, and allows you to create multiple such bookmarks!

*Note: If I open Jupyter in a 2nd environment, I would need the same link but with 8889 (instead of 8888)*